# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, marketing-cloud-connect, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to activate this this query activity to add it in an automation, I'am facing this error syntaxe : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' . I din't build it , I'm juste reusise it. Anybody could tell me what's wrong with it ? Thank you all

```
SELECT
    
    employe.Id as 'ID_User_Employe',
    employe.AccountId as 'ID_Company_Client',
    company.Distributor__c as 'ID_Company_Distributor',
    employe.HP_UserId__c as 'ID_User_HP',
    employe.Salutation as 'Civility',
    employe.LastName as 'Last_Name',
    employe.FirstName as 'First_Name',
    company.Name as 'Company_Name',
    employe.CompanyCode__c as 'Company_Code',
    distributor.Name as 'Distributor_Name',
    employe.Birthdate as 'Birthdate',
    employe.Email as 'Email',
    employe.MobilePhone as 'Mobile_Phone',
    employe.Local__c as 'Country_Code',
    employe.Package_code__c as 'Package_Code',
    employe.LsBloodColMeth__c as 'LiveSmart_Collection_Type',
    recordtype.name as 'Type_User_Employe',
    employe.ActivationLink__c as 'Activation_Link',
    employe.Status__c as 'Status_User_Employe',
    /*employe.DateActivated__c as 'Date_Activated',*/
    employe.DateRegistered__c as 'Date_Registered',
    employe.DateTerminated__c as 'Date_Terminated',
    employe.OptinCommercialPolicy__c as 'Optin_Commercial_Policy',
    /*employe.UnsubscribeLink__c as 'Unsubscribe_Link'*/

    FROM ENT.Contact_Salesforce_1 employe WITH (NOLOCK)
    
    INNER JOIN ENT.Account_Salesforce company WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (
    employe.AccountId = company.Id        
    )  
    
    INNER JOIN ENT.Account_Salesforce distributor WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (
    company.Distributor__c = distributor.Id        
    )       
    
    LEFT JOIN ENT.RecordType_Salesforce recordtype WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ( 
    recordtype.Id = employe.RecordTypeId
    )
```

Comment: Can you check by removing `,` in this line `employe.OptinCommercialPolicy__c as 'Optin_Commercial_Policy',`

Comment: Hi There, 

Issue resolved,  I deleted comments and remove the comma right before FROM and it works !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        employe.Id as 'ID_User_Employe',
        employe.AccountId as 'ID_Company_Client',
        company.Distributor__c as 'ID_Company_Distributor',
        employe.HP_UserId__c as 'ID_User_HP',
        employe.Salutation as 'Civility',
        employe.LastName as 'Last_Name',
        employe.FirstName as 'First_Name',
        company.Name as 'Company_Name',
        employe.CompanyCode__c as 'Company_Code',
        distributor.Name as 'Distributor_Name',
        employe.Birthdate as 'Birthdate',
        employe.Email as 'Email',
        employe.MobilePhone as 'Mobile_Phone',
        employe.Local__c as 'Country_Code',
        employe.Package_code__c as 'Package_Code',
        employe.LsBloodColMeth__c as 'LiveSmart_Collection_Type',
        recordtype.name as 'Type_User_Employe',
        employe.ActivationLink__c as 'Activation_Link',
        employe.Status__c as 'Status_User_Employe',
        /*employe.DateActivated__c as 'Date_Activated',*/
        employe.DateRegistered__c as 'Date_Registered',
        employe.DateTerminated__c as 'Date_Terminated',
        employe.OptinCommercialPolicy__c as 'Optin_Commercial_Policy'
        /*employe.UnsubscribeLink__c as 'Unsubscribe_Link'*/
    
        FROM ENT.Contact_Salesforce_1 employe
        INNER JOIN ENT.Account_Salesforce company ON employe.AccountId = company.Id   
        INNER JOIN ENT.Account_Salesforce distributor ON company.Distributor__c = distributor.Id        
        LEFT JOIN ENT.RecordType_Salesforce recordtype ON recordtype.Id = employe.RecordTypeId
```

I have removed the comma at the of the line `employe.OptinCommercialPolicy__c as 'Optin_Commercial_Policy'`

Also,

> To ensure that queries are executed without blocking from other SQL
> updates, query activities use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ
> UNCOMMITTED. This is equal to WITH (NOLOCK). **Using the NOLOCK query**
> **hint is unnecessary**.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5